# Save wfdb output as an image

Tags: python

I am trying to plot ECG signals using wfbd package
It is working but I can't save the output in an image file.
here is the code I am using:

```
record = wfdb.rdrecord('ptb/records100/00000/00001_lr') 
wfdb.plot_wfdb(record=record, title='ECG', figsize=(20,20))
  
fig1=plt.figure()
fig1.savefig('test.png', dpi=100)
```

the image saved is always empty

anyone suggestions ?

Comment: what did you expect `fig1` to contain given you plot nothing in it?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is save the figure object that wfdb plotted the signal to.
However, you're creating a new figure and saving it.

`wfdb.plot_wfdb` has a `return_fig` argument to get the figure object you want.
Call `savefig` on that object.
[Doc here](https://wfdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plot.html#wfdb.plot.plot_wfdb)

```py
fig = wfdb.plot_wfdb(..., return_fig=True)
fig.savefig("test.png")
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked :) I have already tried the return figure before but it didn't work as I did not know there was an option return_fig=True . Thanks again for your help :)